# What are these tags @ivar @param and @type in python docstring?

Tags: python, documentation, javadoc

The ampoule project uses some tags in docstring, like the javadoc ones.

For example from [pool.py](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dialtone/ampoule/main/annotate/26?file_id=pool.py-20080501191749-jqawtxogk4i0quu3-12) line 86:

```
def start(self, ampChild=None):
    """
    Starts the ProcessPool with a given child protocol.

    @param ampChild: a L{ampoule.child.AMPChild} subclass.
    @type ampChild: L{ampoule.child.AMPChild} subclass
    """
```

What are these tags, which tool uses it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Markup for a documentation tool, probably [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 15):

Just for fun I'll note that the Python standard library is using Sphinx/reStructuredText, whose [info field lists](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html) are similar.

```
def start(self, ampChild=None):
    """Starts the ProcessPool with a given child protocol.

    :param ampChild: a :class:`ampoule.child.AMPChild` subclass.
    :type ampChild: :class:`ampoule.child.AMPChild` subclass
    """
```

Comment: How many convection for the same programming language! Bad thing.

Comment: @Andrea Francia: Epydoc is very lightweight (nowhere near as powerful as reStructuredText) and was developed well before reStructuredText was adopted as a standard. They both have good reason for existing, though I'd recommend users go with reStructuredText from here forward.

Comment: And there's also the lightweight notation mentioned in PEP 257, which is not targeted towards tools, but human readability.