# How to generate documentation using Pydoc

Tags: python, documentation, pydoc

I need to generate documentation from comments using pydoc. What are the basic steps to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want to use Pydoc, you can simply do in a terminal:

```
$ pydoc -w myproject
```

This will generate an old-school HTML documentation from doctrings.
Note that Pydoc is the module used in Python since 2.1 for the `help()` function.
It will retrieve the *docstrings* which are NOT *comments*. You should describe your functions using docstrings.

But it is a kind of old-school using Pydoc for documentation generating.
The popular tool to do that in Python is [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/). But you'll need to format your docstrings in a particular format as reStructuredText.

You could also use [pdoc](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc), which auto-extracts documentation from your docstrings (i.e. public API) and supports markdown, numpydoc, google-style docstrings format and some reStructuredText directives.

Have a look [here](http://daouzli.com/blog/docstring.html) to get some information concerning docstrings formatting.

You can also use [Pyment](https://github.com/dadadel/pyment) to generate docstring skeletons or convert existing ones to a particular format.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you want a simple text file instead of HTML, you can redirect the console output to a file with this simple command:

```
$ pydoc myproject > helpfile.txt
```

This file can be printed or uploaded to Github without too much additional effort.